# Criar lista HTML com retorno de consulta SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Preciso retornar a consulta *SQL* em uma lista *HTML*.
No caso preciso de linha com "filial" e "nome", a consulta abaixo,retornou corretamente os dados requisitado, mas preciso agora colocar esses dados um seguido do outro em uma lista *HTML*.

```
//iniciando a conexão com o banco de dados
$cx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

//selecionando o banco de dados
$db = mysqli_select_db($cx, "dados");

//criando a query de consulta à tabela criada
$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT * FROM esocial") or die(
    mysqli_error($cx) //caso haja um erro na consulta
);

//pecorrendo os registros da consulta.
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "-----------------------------------------<br />";
    echo "Filial:".$aux["filial"]."<br />";
    echo "CPF:".$aux["cpfTrab"]."<br />";
    echo "PIS:".$aux["nisTrab"]."<br />";
    echo "Sexo:".$aux["sexo"]."<br />";
    echo "Raça/Cor:".$aux["racaCor"]."<br />";
    echo "Estado Civil:".$aux["estCiv"]."<br />";
    echo "Grau Instrução:".$aux["grauIntr"]."<br />";
    echo "Data Nascimento:".$aux["dtNascto1"]."<br />";
    echo "Cod. Município:".$aux["codMunic1"]."<br />";
    echo "UF:".$aux["uf1"]."<br />";
    echo "País Nascimento:".$aux["paisNascto"]."<br />";
    echo "País Nacionalidade:".$aux["paisNac"]."<br />";
    echo "Nome Mãe:".$aux["nmMae"]."<br />";
    echo "Nome Pai:".$aux["nmPai"]."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes do `forech` você abre a lista `<ul>` ou `<ol>`, dentro coloca os dados entre `<li> </li>` e depois fecha `</ul>` ou `</ol>`:

```
echo "<ul>";
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo "<li> Filial:".$aux["filial"]." - Nome: ".$aux["nome"]."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Para mostrar numa tabela é só mudar as tags HTML:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%">
        <col width="50%">
        <col width="25%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>CPF</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$aux["nome"]."</td>
                        <td>".$aux["cpf"]."</td>
                        <td>".$aux["..."]."</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`thead` define o cabeçalho da tabela, `tbody` o corpo da tabela, `tfoot` o rodapé da tabela e `colgroup` define o estio das colunas (você pode mudar outros atributos do HTML, no caso eu só usei para definir a largura da coluna)

Isso?

Comment: Guilherme, a consulta está ok, o que preciso é montar um cabeçalho com; FILIAL CPF PIS SEXO RACA e assim por diante, e cada resultado fique em lista embaixo do respectivo nome. exemplo; FILIAL CPF PIS SEXO
0000 XXX XXX XXXX
1111 ZZZ ZZZ ZZZZ....